# change java script anchor scroll to look for array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scroll

I have some JavaScript that currently looks for `_target` and anchors to target.
I wish to change it to look for a array `[_target_index]` however I cant seem to get this to work every time I try I get errors.

When I console.log my array I get my expected array output.

Can someone help me addend  y code to accept the array rather than just `_target` ?

**What I tried**

```
 _scrollTopPixels = (anchorElementArray [_target_index]).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight + _pdpSectionsHeight);
```

**console error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: anchorElementArray[_target_index].offset is not a function
```

**My full code**

```
 _pdpNavigationScrollTo = function () {
        _pdpLink.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _fixedNavHeight, _target, _target_index, _scrollTopPixels;

            if (!INFORMA.global.device.isDesktop) {


                _target = $(this).data('target');
                _target_index = $(this).data('target-index');

                $('#pdp-sections').slideUp();
                _pdpNavigationHeight = $('#pdp-navigation .nav-pdp-nondesktop').outerHeight();


                if (!_pdpFixed)
                    _pdpSectionsHeight = $('#pdp-sections').height();
                else
                    _pdpSectionsHeight = 0;

                _fixedNavHeight = _navHeightMobile;
                var anchorElementArray = $("[id='" + _target + "']");

                console.log(anchorElementArray[_target_index]);

                if (anchorElementArray.length >= [_target_index]) {

                    //_scrollTopPixels = $("#" + _target).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight + _pdpSectionsHeight);
                     _scrollTopPixels = (anchorElementArray [_target_index]).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight + _pdpSectionsHeight);
                } else {
                    _scrollTopPixels = $("#" + _target).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight + _pdpSectionsHeight);
                }
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: _scrollTopPixels
                }, 1000);

            } else {
                _target = $(this).data('target');
                $('#pdp-navigation li').removeClass('selected');
                $('#pdp-navigation li').addClass('select-options');
                _pdpNavigationHeight = _pdpNavigation.height();
                _fixedNavHeight = _navHeight;

                _scrollTopPixels = $("#" + _target).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: _scrollTopPixels
                }, 1000);
            }

        })
    };
```

Comment: my guess would require you to create a jquery object to access the offset method, `$(anchorElementArray[_target_index]).offset().top`

Comment: @Steve0 I think that may do it cheers mate

Comment: It is always easier for us to help if you include both the HTML and the JavaScript in an actual working minimal example as a snippet (CTRL-M when you are editing)

Comment: Just beware the 3.0 jQuery breaking change https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-invalid-input-to-the-offset-method

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thanks mark ill keep this in mind when we upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jQuery` method `offset` requires a jQuery object to access it, as such you need to change;

```
(anchorElementArray[_target_index]).offset().top
```

to

```
$(anchorElementArray[_target_index]).offset().top
```